# Where are the logfiles for worldserver Docker containers?

Tags: docker, azerothcore

My worldserver.conf.dockerdist file has this added:

```
LogLevel = 3
LogFileLevel = 3
```

The other settings in the above file are the ones that came with the file and are not shown here. Logs directory remain as 'LogsDir = "/azeroth-server/logs"'

Using interactive mode, I saw that the "/azeroth-server/log" directory in the worldserver container is empty. I am expecting logs to be generated there.

I verified that worldserver.conf has been copied correctly into the container by checking contents using interactive mode.

May I know how do I get the log files generated?

Comment: what actual docker container did you use? Can you show the commands that you used so far? And what is this interactive mode you refer to?

Answer (score 2):

Found out that it was due to an error in the config files for the container.

Wrong:

```
LogsDir = "/azeroth-server/logs" # will reflect on your host directory: docker/worldserver/logs
```

Right:

```
LogsDir = "/azeroth-server/logs"
```

The "# will reflect on your host directory: docker/worldserver/logs" should not be on the same line as the LogsDir variable.

Comment: Hmm yes, i think that we can't write inline # comments in server conf files, not sure why :(

Comment: @Barbz_YHOOL I printed out the string variable (m_logsDir in Log.cpp) that stores the logs directory to stdout and saw that the comment got included, which was how I found out. Maybe we can write something up to remove anything including and after "#"?

Comment: report the issue on the repo maybe?